# What does in JSX react <div css=?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple react component it has in the JSX the property `css`, I understand this prop it is for styling, but it is not clear if it is a "native" css react property, or if it comes from `styled-components` or some other library.

Do you have an idea from which library it is if not a react one?

```
<div css={{color: 'red', backgroundColor:'blue'}}>Hello world!</div>;
```

Comment: Not sure, here's a list for you to check against https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js

Answer (score 1):

`css` prop comes from `styled-components` library itself. It is to be used when a small bit of styling does not warrant making a component for it.

However, it is not implemented centrally in the library and functions with the help of the [Babel plugin](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin). This is why you don't need to import the function to use it.

[Docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop)

Answer (score 0):

It comes from [Glamor](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor) which provides many convenient ways to style your components. One way is to use its css prop as in your example. It works exactly the same as the default style prop except it supports the entire CSS language.

Here an example:
https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/blob/master/docs/howto.md